# OpenCV with kinect begineer's doubts

Tags: image-processing, opencv, kinect, openni

I have OpenCV and libfreenect configured on my ubuntu 11.04 and works seperately.
I also have some experience with OpenCV but the problem is i don't know how to combine both kinect and OpenCV.I was hoping if someone would kindly help me out by pointing to a good documentation or providing a simple sample code of using kinect in opencv.

Answer (score 3):

The first link on google for "OpenCV kinect" was [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Kinect). I hope it helps.

Comment: Since i had to go the hard way i decided to contribute

Answer (score 2):

To quickly get things working, I would recommend including opencv libraries to one of the openni samples (for example NiUserTracker). There you can acquire the depth image from the DepthMetaData object in the following way.

```
//obtain depth image
DepthMetaData depthMD;
g_DepthGenerator.GetMetaData(depthMD);
const XnDepthPixel* g_Depth = depthMD.Data();
cv::Mat DepthBuf(480,640,CV_16UC1,(unsigned char*)g_Depth);
//To display the depth image you probably would want to normalize it to 0-255 range first


//obtain rgb image
ImageMetaData ImageMD;
g_ImageGenerator.GetMetaData(ImageMD);
const XnUInt8* g_Img =ImageMD.Data();
cv::Mat ImgBuf(480,640,CV_8UC3,(unsigned short*)g_Img);
cv::Mat ImgBuf2;
cv::cvtColor(ImgBuf,ImgBuf2,CV_RGB2BGR);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get work MrglMrgl code, I've had to add the following at the beginning:

```
nRetVal = g_Context.FindExistingNode(XN_NODE_TYPE_IMAGE, g_ImageGenerator);
if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
{
     printf("No image node exists! Check your XML.");
     return 1;
}
```

And this at the final:

```
cv::namedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
cv::imshow( "Example1", ImgBuf2 );
cv::waitKey(0);
```